# html how to copy html page with border and use as email signature in gmail

Tags: html, css

*Here is the html code. How do I copy the the whole page and use as my email signature. 
*

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>

<body>


  <div style="border-radius: 25px; border:2px solid #446cdb; padding: 20px; width:400px; height:170px;">
    <img align="left" src="http://yourwebsiteengineer.com/icons/Helmet.png" nosend="1" border="0" width="150" height="90" alt="coding" />

    <table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" border="0">
      <tbody>

        <tr>
          <td valign="left" style="padding-left: 2px; padding-top: 1px; padding-bottom: 1px; padding-right: 1px;">
            <span style="text-align: left; color: #000000; font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; font-weight: bold">Victor
    / Intern</span>
            <br>
            <span style="text-align: left; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; color: #000000; font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-size: 9pt;">IT Department</span>
            <br>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td valign="top" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">
            <span style="text-align: left; color: #000000; font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 11pt; font-weight: bold"> Communications Ltd.</span>
            <br>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td valign="top" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">
            <span style="text-align: left; color: #000000; font-family: Arial; font-size: 9pt; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal;">No 12b kenneth Agbakuru street <font size="1" color="#B9B9B9">|</font> HSG estate <br>Lekki Phase1 Lagos, Nigeria.<br><font color="#B9B9B9"> Tel:</font> +   </span>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td valign="top" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">
            <span style="text-align: left; margin-top: 0px; color: #F77A1E; font-size: 9pt; font-weight: bold; font-family: 'Calibri', sans-serif;">
    <a style="text-decoration: none; color: #1e1ef7" href="http://www.optiwebn.com/" target="_blank"><font color="#2d26de">w:</font> <font color="#000000">www.cahefun.com</font></a>  <font size="1" color="#B9B9B9">|</font><br> <a style="text-decoration: none; color: #F77A1E" href="mailto:victor.adewale@optiwebng.com" target="_blank"><font color="#1e1ef7">e:</font> <font color="#000000">jacob66@gmail.com</font></a>
</span>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td valign="top" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 7px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">
            <a href="http://twitter.com/haddy_whales" target="_blank">
              <img src="http://yourwebsiteengineer.com/icons/twitter.png" nosend="1" border="0" width="21" height="17" alt="Twitter" />
            </a>
            <a href="http://www.facebook.com/vadewale2" target="_blank">
              <img src="http://yourwebsiteengineer.com/icons/facebook.png" nosend="1" border="0" width="21" height="17" alt="Facebook" />
            </a>
            <a href="https://ng.linkedin.com/in/victor-adewale-8a3718114" target="_blank">
              <img src="http://yourwebsiteengineer.com/icons/linkedin.png" nosend="1" border="0" width="21" height="17" alt="LinkedIn" />
            </a><a href="https://www.instagram.com/haddy_whales/" target="_blank" />
            <img src="images%20(1).jpg" nosend="1" border="0" width="21" height="17" alt="LinkedIn">
            </a>
          </td>
        </tr>



      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

<style>
  a {
    color: #F77A1E;
  }
</style>

</html>
```

**Here is the html code. How do I copy the the whole page and use as my email signature. 
**

> how do I copy the border along with the content in it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want image of html then save your html as canvas image, and include that image in your mail body.

Or if you want pure html then by javascript/jquery take all html of body by innerHTML/html() method respectively and send it as mail body.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an email client like outlook, or thunderbird.

To use a signature in Outlook:

On the Home tab, choose New Email.

On the Message tab, in the Include group, choose Signature > Signatures.

Signature command

Under Select signature to edit, choose New, and in the New Signature dialog box, type a name for the signature.

Under Choose default signature, do the following:

In the E-mail account list, choose an email account to associate with the signature.

In the New messages list, choose the signature that you want to be added automatically to all new email messages. If you don't want to auto sign your email messages, accept the default option of (none).

In the Replies/forwards list, choose the signature that you want to be added automatically (auto sign) when you reply to or forward messages. Otherwise, accept the default option of (none).

Under Edit signature, type the signature, and then choose OK.

Answer (score 0):

http://rajputproud.blogspot.in/p/blog-page_25.html

Click this links and Copy your Signature and paste is in email signature,

i tested it . :)